# C++ Floating point exception with global list array

Tags: c++, arrays, list, floating-point

I'm just getting started, but I'm already having trouble.  So far, my code is simply:

(In Searcher.h)

```
#ifndef SEARCHER_H
#define SEARCHER_H

#include <string>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

class Searcher{

 public:
  Searcher( int& x );
  ~Searcher();

 private:
  int size;
  list<string> * lists;
};
#endif
```

(In Searcher.cpp)

```
#include "Searcher.h"
Searcher::Searcher (int& x){
  lists = new list<string>[x];
}
```

(In testSearcher.cpp)

```
#include "Searcher.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main (){
   Searcher * x = new Searcher(211);
}
```

It compiles, but when I run it, it gives a floating point exception.  I even replaced x with 211 to no avail.  Thank you in advance for any help.  Also, to amateur debug it, I put a cout statement in the constructor before the initialization and it printed fine, then g++ gave me the floating point exception.

Comment: Please post the complete code, not some fragment. The above code doesn’t cause the exception, although it has its own share of problems.

Comment: @Robert - edit the question, don't post code in a comment

Comment: @Robert:  That tells us nothing.  There's nothing there that will cause a floating-point exception.  Edit the question to include enough code to trigger the exception.  You may well have to do some work yourself to trim the code down to something that can be posted and easily read and still cause the exception.  Right now, there is nothing we can do to help you (aside from telling you never to use `using namespace std;` in a header).

Comment: That's literally all I have so far, I'm just getting started.  That's why I was confused.

Comment: I just compiled what you posted with g++.  I needed to make a couple changes though.  Searcher(int &x) should just be Searcher(int x) as there is no reason for it to be a reference and you can't pass a const (i.e. - 211) to it (I'm not sure how you got that to compile).  Additionally I added a return 0; to your main function.  It ran without and problems.

Comment: The posted code won't even compile for me - not surprising, 211 cannot possibly be passed as an `int&`. With that changed, it runs but it's not setting up lists the way you want. Why are you using raw pointers and arrays here anyway?

Comment: @Robert:  What sort of floating-point exception?  There is absolutely no floating-point processing going on.  Could you post the exact error message you're getting?

Comment: Floating point exception (core dumped)

Comment: I didn't pass 211, I changed it to lists = new list<string>[211];

Comment: @David - the code leaves `lists` in a useless state, so I am sure that much hypothetical follow-on usage will cause an exception, though the code above does not. OP needs guidance on better C++ style I think.

Comment: @Steve Townsend - what makes you say his code leaves `lists` in a useless state?

Comment: I am just attempting to learn this on my own, so I'm sure my code is riddled with errors.  I temporarily solved it with setting the global variable to list<string> lists[211];  Thank you for all of your help and quick responses.

Comment: @Niki - observation of locals in the debugger - eg. `size` not initialized

Answer (score 0):

Try making the parameter to Searcher "const int &x".

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be:

```
Searcher::Searcher (int& x) {
    lists = new list<string>(x);
}
```

I've never seen the syntax you posted with the [x].